# retrieving data from pandas group by object

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have pandas group by object with output as below.

```
                  items
month_name year        
Apr        2001   98714
Dec        2000  146381
Feb        2001   82279
Jan        2001   77016
Mar        2001  102462
May        2001   53898
```

I would like to however transform it as a basic data frame as below (with all
indexes and columns of group by object becoming columns of the new data frame).

```
month_name year  Items      
Apr        2001   98714
Dec        2000  146381
Feb        2001   82279
Jan        2001   77016
Mar        2001  102462
May        2001   53898
```

I would need to do pivot on this new dataframe for further processing.  I know
 it is straightforward and for some reason not getting it.  Thanks much

Comment: As basic as `df = df.reset_index()`

Comment: guys...got it...thanks...